# Need help creating a DAX measure to count distinct status by groupkey and max date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write a couple DAX expressions to count the number of [Status] by [GroupKey] and maximum [TxDate]. For example, the end result should only be counting the below records with the max TxDate and group by GroupKey to show that [CountOfFailures] = 3 and [CountOfSuccess] = 2.

```
TxDate          Status  GroupKey
9/29/2020 0:00  Failure ABC
9/29/2020 0:00  Failure ABC
9/29/2020 0:00  Failure ABC
9/30/2020 0:00  Success ABC
9/25/2020 0:00  Failure XYZ
9/27/2020 0:00  Failure XYZ
9/28/2020 0:00  Failure XYZ
9/29/2020 10:00 Failure XYZ
9/29/2020 13:00 Failure XYZ
9/29/2020 15:00 Failure XYZ
9/26/2020 0:00  Success EFG
9/27/2020 0:00  Success EFG
9/28/2020 0:00  Success EFG
9/28/2020 0:00  Failure LMN
9/29/2020 0:00  Failure LMN
9/30/2020 22:00 Failure LMN
9/26/2020 0:00  Failure QRS
9/30/2020 00:00 Failure QRS
```

Currently my DAX expression for counting failures counts ALL of the failures but again my requirement is to count Status and group by the max date and GroupKey.

```
 NumberOfFailures =

 VAR noOfFailureTransactions=

 CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[Status] = "Failure"))
 RETURN

 IF ( ISBLANK( noOfFailureTransactions), 0, noOfFailureTransactions
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for that:

[image]

```
CountFailure =
VAR _maxDate =
    TREATAS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( MyTable[GroupKey] ),
            "maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'MyTable'[TxDate] ) )
        ),
        MyTable[GroupKey],
        MyTable[TxDate]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( MyTable[GroupKey], MyTable[Status], _maxDate ) ),
        MyTable[Status] = "Failure"
    )
```

And second measure:

```
CountSuccess =
VAR _maxDate =
    TREATAS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( MyTable[GroupKey] ),
            "maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'MyTable'[TxDate] ) )
        ),
        MyTable[GroupKey],
        MyTable[TxDate]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( MyTable[GroupKey], MyTable[Status], _maxDate ) ),
        MyTable[Status] = "Success"
    )
```

Comment: It works great! If I can't use the GroupKey anymore and need to rely on two different fields to establish uniqueness, how would I go about re-writing this DAX expression?

Comment: change this:
TREATAS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( MyTable[GroupKey] ),
            "maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'MyTable'[TxDate] ) )
        ),
        MyTable[GroupKey],
        MyTable[TxDate]
    )

to:

TREATAS(
ADDCOLUMNS (
ALL( MyTable[Column1], MyTable[Column2]),
"maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'MyTable'[TxDate] ) )
        ),
        MyTable[Column1],
        MyTable[Column2],
        MyTable[TxDate]
    )